# SSMS crashing after I paste a very large piece of code on it

Tags: sql-server, windows, ssms

I am trying to paste a large UNION ALL script construct on SSMS. But the moment I paste it, the SSMS crashes automatically. If it helps, the code is of the structure :

```
select ID from (
select '00123' ID UNION ALL
select '00124' ID UNION ALL
select '00126' ID UNION ALL
select '00129' ID UNION ALL
select '00131' ID UNION ALL
....
select '98254' ID) tab
```

There are 30,000 plus "select". I am on SSMS 2012 version - 11.0.3513.0 . The `OS` is Windows 7 Professional (64 bit) and the RAM is 64 GB.

Things I have tried -

- instead of pasting, created a `.sql` file and then using it with the content so that the clipboard is not choked.
- using excel's "connect to sql server" option. But, it's trimming a chunk of code when I paste into the "SQL" text box.

What do I need to do to get it running?

Comment: You should really insert that data into a table instead of using 30,000 `SELECT`s

Comment: Also, what does "crashes" mean here?, does it throw an error?, if so, what's the error message?

Comment: The real issue is now that ssms is crashing before I can do anything. I am getting these IDs from an excel file and I need to run some sort of look up in one of the tables.

Comment: so, what does "crashing" mean??, can you explain?

Comment: crashes as in wooosh..vanish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQLCMD to run sql script from command prompt

```
sqlcmd -S <ComputerName>\<InstanceName> -i <MyScript.sql> -o outp.txt
```

Comment: But these number of scipts work fine normally in ssms with 8gb of RAM machine itself

Answer (score 4):

Crash is happening most probably because of the intellsense, trying to parse UNION case, which is complicated.
Using VALUES statement would make the query easier to parse. (If not - try disabling Intellisense)

```
SELECT * 
FROM (VALUES('00123'),
            ('00124'),
            ('00125')) as t(v)
```